# Traverse VPN tunnel from static IP address?

Tags: networking, routes, vpn, router, portforwarding

I have a VPN tunnel set up between two routers. Router A has a static IP address. Router B uses dynamic DNS. This tunnel works perfectly if I want to access Router B as if it were part of my network when I am using a computer on Router A.

However, what I'd like to do is access the machines on Router B over the internet via Router A's static IP.

So, basically, here's what I'd like to do. Say Router B has the IP address of 192.168.20.X. When I am on Router A, I am easily able to access machines with this address. But, what I'd like to do (from outside of Router A) is access Router B using port forwarding.

So, if I use Router A's IP address (e.g. 123.456.789.000) and do something like 123.456.789.000:978, I'd like to access a machine at 192.168.20.12.

I've added services to my router (Router A is a NetGear SRX3508, Router B is a Cradlepoint IBR400) for port forwarding, but it doesn't work. Any links or advice?

Comment: What is the EXACT "port forwarding" configuration you're using, and how *exactly* does it not work? Also (and not sure if this is something you care about), port forwarding and VPNs are not really related when it comes to traffic flow.

Comment: I'll be entirely honest, networking isn't my forte, so any information (e.g. regarding VPNs and port forwarding) is useful.  

On my NetGear, I have a service/port forward for port 678 going to 192.168.20.21:80, which is a camera's web server on the other end. When I use my static IP 123.456.789.000:678, it does nothing.  

I'm not exactly sure how to set something like this up. The reason I'm wanting it, is so I can create a centralized server that allows me to control access to IP cameras for various users by administering custom ports to forward them to their cameras.

Comment: Does your NetGear actually have a public IP assigned to it by your ISP? And can you confirm that your ISP doesn't do any inbound filtering themselves? (and obviously I assume that `123.456.789.000` is an example, since that's rather invalid ;)

Comment: I have got a public IP assigned, as I can get to the router from the IP address. I'm able to port forward to a whole slew of other services (VNC, web servers, etc), but I cannot send a port over the VPN. And yes, that's just the example IP address. That much I know, ha ha.

Comment: Ok. With the VPN running: from a machine at `A` are you able to ping `router B`'s inside interface (this should be the default gateway IP of the machines at `B`)?

Comment: I am able to ping machine B through machine A, using the "Ping through VPN tunnel" option. Without that option selected, I'm unable to ping machine B. Because of this option being selected, is there anything I should look for inside of machine A that exists in regards to a port over VPN?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a VPN here? It is a simple case of hosting server in a LAN and exposing it through gw, if I understand your requirement correctly. if you have server a:p and router A, you should have a port forwarding / PAT config for A:p to a. you should make sure to send the packets to A:P and the portforward logic will send the packet to your lan server which is a.

Comment: No, he's looking to access a host at B via A's public/static IP, through the VPN from A to B. This, versus attempting to access via B's non-static public connection.